# How Decode HTML in MVC with RAZOR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using MVC 3 and Razor as View Engine, for my understanding HTML tags are decoding by default to prevent XSS attacks or similar. (I'm also using MS XSS 4.2.1 Library)

I have a View showing some data

```
<div class="display-label">Code</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Code).
</div>
```

Model.Code is HTML code for some Banners, I need to display the HTML on the page DECODED.
My question: How can I decode the HTML for just `model.Code` living the rest ENCODED?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display raw html use

```
@Html.Raw(model.Code)
```

Be extremely careful though

Comment: what are the security risks involved

Comment: [Cross site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) being a major security risk

Answer (score 1):

you can use to output the data as is without encoding :

```
@Html.Raw(model.Code)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use is `@MvcHtmlString.Create(@Model.OurVision)`