# Url parameter values with special characters and IE

Tags: c#, html, internet-explorer, razor

Have a webpage that is opened from another system with parameters that can contain extended ascii characters:

```
http://<host>/submitpage.cshtml?pname=SomeName
```

The cshtml webpage reads the parameters as usual with:

```
var pname = Request["pname"];
```

and shows it on the page with `@pname`

Works fine for all browsers except IE (even IE11) when pname=Günther or another name with foreign characters; ü, ø and so on.

```
Example:
http://<host>/submitpage.cshtml?pname=Günther
results in G�nther
```

The webpage is using `<meta charset="UTF-8" />`

Any solution? I have no control over the submitting system, som the url cannot be encoded before submit.

Comment: Have you tried this? [Display encoded html with razor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029264/display-encoded-html-with-razor)

Comment: Or this? [How Decode HTML in MVC with RAZOR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305787/how-decode-html-in-mvc-with-razor)

Answer (score 0):

So between RFC3986 and RFC2234, we have the following relevant rules for URIs

```
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"

sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
                / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="

HEXDIG        =  DIGIT / "A" / "B" / "C" / "D" / "E" / "F"

pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG

query         = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )

unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"

ALPHA         =  %x41-5A / %x61-7A   ; A-Z / a-z

DIGIT         =  %x30-39 ; 0-9
```

so any implementation that accepts the unencoded letter ü is non-standards compliant and any user agent issuing requests with such characters is also non-compliant. It sounds like you know that this is the case.

IMO, it's a dangerous game making your own system more permissive to patch over the faults of "out of your control" systems. Are you sure the issuer of this request can't fix their code?

Comment: Yes, there is no way we can change the parameters.

Comment: But why isn't this a problem in Opera and Chrome?